# ngForm sending undefined to ngSubmit function

Tags: angular

**HTML**

```
<form class="row"  #stepOneForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "updateDetails(stepOneForm)">
  <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="row">
      {{stepOneForm.valid}}
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="">Select Loan Type:</label>
        <select class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)] = "loan_data.loan_type"
          #loanType = "ngModel"
          name = "loan_type"
          required
        >

          <option value="1">Personal Loan</option>
          <option value="2">Home Loan</option>
          <option value="3">Car Loan</option>
          <option value="4">Business Loan</option>
          <option value="5">Two wheeler Loan</option>
          <option value="6">Education Loan</option>
        </select>
      <div class ="error"  *ngIf = "loanType.touched && loanType.errors?.required">
        Plese select loan Type.
      </div>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
updateDetails(f:NgForm) {
    if(!f.valid || !this.validateDetails()){
      this.validation_errors["form_error"] = true;
      console.log(f.valid);
      return;
    }   }
```

In this it's throwing error ,

> Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

please help me about this , it has taken almost 2 hours time to me.

Comment: Are you using reactive form or template based form

Comment: I am using reactive form

Comment: you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` and `FormsModule` in app.module and import `Formgroup,FormBuilder,FormControl` in your component ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<form class="row"  [formGroup]="stepOneForm" (ngSubmit) = "updateDetails(stepOneForm)">
 ....
</form>
```

Assign the form group name in the template in this manner and pass the form name on submit. Hope this will work for you.

Comment: This is for reactive form validation, there should be a formGroup declared at ts file with the help of formbuilder for this to work.

Comment: it is giving error like this, Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'